# Big O complexity: T(n) = O(f(n)), G(n) = O(h(n)). Is T(G(n)) = O(h(f(n)))?

Tags: performance, time, big-o

```
T(n)= O(f(n)), G(n)= O(h(n))
```

How would I prove or disprove:

```
  T(G(n))= O(h(f(n))
```

I think this is **false**, because it should be O(f(h(n))) instead of O(h(f(n))), since G is applied before T is applied, I tried substituting polynomial functions for T and G, I think the order matters, (n^2)! is not equal to (n!)^2 , but I am not sure if this reasoning is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this is false, however I did not quite understand your counterexample.
A counterexample would be to take a function and its inverse, while keeping h very small asymptotically:

`T(n) = 2^n , f(n) = 2^n` This is compliant with the given fact that `2^n = O(2^n)`
And
`G(n) = lg(n!) , h(n) = n lg(n)` This is also compliant with the given fact that `lg(n!) < O(lg n^n) = O(n lg n)`

However, `T(G(n)) = 2^(lg(n!)) = n!` and `h(f(n)) = 2^n lg(2^n) = n*2^n` but, `n! =/= O(n*2^n)` as we have a factorial function vs an exponent function (multiplied by a linear function) thus we proved it is not true.

---

The reason `n! =/= O(n 2^n)` is because: `n*2^n < 2^n * 2^n = 4^n` and we know that a factorial function 'beats' an exponent.